# Creating Runnable jar file of lower version

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, executable-jar, runnable-jar

I currently have java version of 1.8 but i want to make a Runnable jar file of version 1.7 through eclipse because i'm not able to execute the generated jar file of version 1.8 on the server. So that, I want to downgrade the version of the jar file. Please tell me some steps to do it.

Comment: Compile it with a java 1.7 compiler? I'm not sure I understand if you're asking for directions on how to change the compiler version in eclipse or what.

Comment: Do you use any Java 8 features like lambdas? If so you will need to rewrite that code as those features were added in Java 8

Comment: Which kind of projects are you using? For instance If it's a faceted project you should change the compiler version in project properties, if it's a maven project you can do it on POM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your java compilation version on project level to Java 1.7 and then make jar from eclipse:

Go to project setting `Right click -> Properties`

[image]